# How to use and print from constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to create a simple card game where two players receive random cards. I have decided to use the constructor to make it simple and use less space. Can someone help me and explain how to generate random card in my main program from my Card class.

```
public class clsCard {

    private int value;
    private int rank, suit;
    private final int MaxFaceValue= 10;
    private static String[] suits = {"Joker","hearts","spades","diamond","clubs"};
    private static String[] ranks = {"Joker","Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};

    public clsCard(int suit, int rank)
    {
        this.rank= (int)(Math.random()*ranks.length);
        this.suit= (int)(Math.random()*suits.length);
    }

    public @Override String toString()
    {
        if(ranks[rank].equals("Joker") || suits[suit].equals("Joker"))
            return "Joker";
        else
        return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }
    public int getRank()
    {
        return rank;
    }
    public int getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `this.rank= ranks[(int)(Math.random()*ranks.length)];`

Comment: You can create list of all possible cards, shuffle it and pick N cards for each player. Each of this steps is already explained at Stack Overflow. Try to apply those solutions and come back when you will face some error/exception/incorrect results.

Comment: You need to make an array containing all cards in your deck; 52 or some more, if you want to have the jokers. For dealing a random card, you compute a random number for the index, which will give you the card. Keep track of the dealt cards, or else.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). 
Please read (and follow) the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Here's a question for you.  In the real world, does shuffling and dealing a deck of cards cause new cards to (magically) appear?  No.  In a computer program, the simplest way is create the deck (non-randomly!), then shuffle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you need all of the cards and then to randomly choose from this. You might need some basic classes to do this. This is just one way to do this - create a deck, something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {

    private ArrayList cards;

    public enum Suit {Joker, Spade, Club, Heart, Diamond};

    public Deck() {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

        // Add all appropriate cards
        for(int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            cards.add(new Card(i, Suit.Spade));
            cards.add(new Card(i, Suit.Club));
            cards.add(new Card(i, Suit.Heart));
            cards.add(new Card(i, Suit.Diamond));
        }

        cards.add(new Card(0, Suit.Joker));
        cards.add(new Card(0, Suit.Joker));

    }

    public Card dealRandomCard() {
        int random = (int)(Math.random()*cards.size());
        Card c = cards.get(random)
        cards.remove(random);
        return c;
    }

}
```

This is with a Card class too, expand on:

```
public class Card {

    public Card(int i, Suit s) {

    }

}
```

Then you can build from there.

Comment: Ok. I know that in real life we would use a deck of cards with a limited amount of cards. The thing is that I have started programming in Java about month ago and wont to keep things simple. I'm just want a easy way to generate a random card. Would clsCard cardFace = new clsCard(); System.out.println("bla" + cardFace); work ? And how would I define clscard constructor?

Comment: I understood that you wanted to keep things simple, the classes I have suggested are simple and should be quite easy to understand.
To do what you want, the constructor should be
    `public clsCard() { this.rank= (int)(Math.random()*ranks.length);  this.suit (int)(Math.random()*suits.length);}`

Then you can call what you desire: `clsCard cardFace = new clsCard();` and call `cardFace.toString();`

HOWEVER, you could easily get the same card twice when you do 'new clsCard()' which a proper solution like mine would avoid.

Comment: Ok :) Can you tell me how to define constructor. I'm asking because when I try this part of the code I receive message saying The constructor clsCard() is undefined

Comment: I defined the constructor in my previous comment.
`public clsCard()
 { 
    this.rank= (int)(Math.random()*ranks.length); 
    this.suit (int)(Math.random()*suits.length);
}`